# "Подкузьмить и объегорить"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда произошла эта поговорка? Почему под раздачу попали именно Кузьма и Егор?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Объегорить*** по происхождению русское слово. В художественные произведения пришло в 19 веке из местных говоров. Образован этот глагол от имени Егор (из Григория). Такое образование объегорить языковеды объясняют тем, что сельскохозяйственные сделки между хозяином и работником заключались в прошлом до праздника святого Георгия (“осеннего Егория”). Невыполнение условия сделки работником или хозяином называли объегориванием.
Образование глагола от собственного имени наблюдается и в других случаях. Так было образовано в диалектах ***подкузьмить*** “обмануть”, “поставить в трудное положение”. Причина образования слова та же: нарушение сделки осенью - в праздник Кузьмы и Демьяна.  (http://slovo.dn.ua/oblaposhit-obegorit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Подкузьмить связано с днем св. Козьмы и Дамиана (17 октября ст. ст.), этот день считался днем истечения сельскохозяйственных сделок (по Фасмеру). Это вполне правдоподобно. С учетом четырех российских неблагоприятных для сельского хозяйства сезонов (зима, весна, лето и очень) "подкузьмившихся" всегда оказывалось предостаточно.

Касательно "объегорить" однозначных версий нет. Вероятно тоже связано связано с днями св. Георгия (Егора, Юрия). По Фасмеру это дни, когда истекали сроки сельскохозяйственных повинностей. Однако в каледнаре таких дней более двух десятков, одного только св. влмч. Георгия Победоносца поминают четыре раза в году. Совершенно ясно, что по версии Фасмера таким днем мог быть только один из осенних Георгиев (10 и 26 ноября ст. ст.) Но достоверных данных о каком-то особенном значении этих дней в торгово-сельскохозяйственом календаре ничего не известно: не сезон, зима в разгаре.
Есть еще версия о том, что "объегорить" связано с названием подмосковного г. Егорьевск, за жителями которого прочно утвердилась слава вралей и плутов, но вряд ли.